How to build a Python Spark bundle with Bazel?
Spark accepts a variety of Python bundle formats:

PEX file
Conda environment
Virtual environment as a tar file

Which of these can be readily built by Bazel from a py_library?
And for those that are viable, how is it done?

Try rules_py. It has a venv rule, which you could make into a tar with rules_pkg.

Do you have an example of that working? The venv rule must be executed; it does not produce an artefact at build-time.

I had a play and found that you can get close, but it's not designed to be portable. It does produce a build-time artefact, but it doesn't list the .<label>_venv directory as a runfile, which means the tar won't grab it. You could do a final tar step with a script you bazel run, but you would need to be careful about how you pack it up and unpack it, as well as handling the BUILD_WORKSPACE_DIRECTORY variable properly.
